# Access arrays/hashes in facter 2 facts

Tags: puppet, facter

In facter 2 you can now have arrays/hashes as facts.

For example:

```
os => {
  "name"=>"CentOS",
  "family"=>"RedHat",
  "release"=>{
    "major"=>"7",
    "minor"=>"0",
    "full"=>"7.0.1406"
  }
}
```

What is the format to access `os=>release=>major` from a manifest?

Answer (score 6):

For example like this:

```
notify { $::os[release][major] : }
```

Note that you need to set the option [stringify_facts](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#stringifyfacts) to false for this to work (default as of writing with Puppet 3.7.1: true).

Comment: That is not a sustainable option though. That option will be depreciated in Puppet 4, so how is it proposed to deal with that then?

Comment: It's my understanding that it will be deprecated in Puppet 4 because the new default will be false then. See https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-406 and  https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2966

Comment: `Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: ::os is not a hash or array when accessing it with name at /etc/puppet/environments/`

Comment: @Alfred: still works for me with latest Puppet 4.x version. Again, stringify_facts = false is the important part here. If it still doesn't work I'd suggest asking a new question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Should be possible access it as usual [hash datatype](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_data_hash.html#lang_data_hash_type).

Example:

```
$myhash = {os => {
  "name"=>"CentOS",
  "family"=>"RedHat",
  "release"=>{
    "major"=>"7",
    "minor"=>"0",
    "full"=>"7.0.1406"
  }
 }
}

notice( $myhash[os][release][major] )
```

Comment: That is what I thought, but it is coming back empty :-/

Comment: // , Has anyone gotten this one to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can access facts from manifests by using hashes, like this:

`notify { $::os['release']['major']: }`

Example:

```
# puppet apply -e 'notify { $::os['release']['major']: }'
Notice: Compiled catalog for mon.adriatic.local in environment production in 0.04 seconds
Notice: 6
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[6]/message: defined 'message' as '6'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.28 seconds
```